# import create_connection fails in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, ibm-cloud

I am writing a websocket program on bluemix and hitting some issues with import create_connection:
     from websocket import create_connection
      ImportError: cannot import name create_connection

May i know what is the fix. I am running on IBM Bluemix with python 2.7

Adding Details:
  I have installed the websocket package in Python notebook and then ran this code:

```
      6 import websocket
      7 print 'before connection'
----> 8 ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://tryandbuyoncloud.stage1.mybluemix.net/ws/Test")

     10 print "Sending 'Hello, World'..."

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create_connection'
```

-Datta

Comment: Heu Datta, can you provide the full log output and your code?

Comment: Do you have a requirements.txt file with the right dependency listed?

Comment: Hi, I do not have requirements.txt, since i am using python notebook and not deploying the app on bluemix.

Comment: Hi Hobert, I have added the program and the error details.

Answer (score 3):

Happened to me today. Seems like the package you were using was `websocket` and not `websocket-client`. Uninstall `websocket` and `websocket-client` (if you have it), and then install `websocket-client` only:

```
pip uninstall websocket
pip uninstall websocket-client
pip install websocket-client
```

Uninstalling `websocket-client` and then reinstalling it may seem redundant, but for me it was necessary (couldn't run `import websocket` after uninstalling `websocket`, even though `websocket-client` was installed).

Answer (score 0):

i was stuck in this error for long, even after uninstalling websocket and installing websocket-client, it was not working. then out of nowhere, doing uninstall and re-install websocket-client solved the error.